# Camera Screen is getting black in Surface pro 9 with vufforia AR in Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, augmented-reality, vuforia, surface-pro

I am making an AR Model Tracking App in  Unity using Vufforia SDK for AR . I have tested with Android Build and it is working fine in android , camera scans model and gives AR trained model . But in Window OS build, I have tested in Surface pro 9 device when the camera is ON Screen getting Black, i don't know what is the reason , i have searched in multi platform but cant get solution.

I tested build in Surface pro 9 but when camera is On Screen looking black , i was expecting like camera will scans model and provide 3d AR model

Comment: Have you followed this guide here? https://developer.vuforia.com/library/getting-started/getting-started-vuforia-engine-windows-10-development

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When building for Windows mobile devices, Vuforia requires the Unity project to be built for the `Universal Windows Platform`.

`Windows, Mac, Linux Standalone` builds are **not** supported by Vuforia.

Please switch your project to the UWP platform in the `Build Settings` window and try to build and run your app on `Local Machine`.

Here's an example of how to configure your Build Settings:

[Build Settings window UWP](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wmc8c.png)